# deploying react + ts vite app via aws amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, vite

i am trying to deploy a react + typescript app that i made using vite to initialize to environment via aws amplify but i am getting the error logs shown below. regarding my node and npm versions, when i check the version on my terminal for node it is v20.9.0 and for npm it is v10.1.0, so im not sure why its saying bad engine.

```
 # Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: npm ci
2024-02-02T04:35:08.224Z [WARNING]: npm
2024-02-02T04:35:08.224Z [WARNING]: WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'rollup@4.9.6',
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0', npm: '>=8.0.0' },
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.19.0', npm: '8.19.3' }
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-02-02T04:35:08.225Z [WARNING]: npm WARN
2024-02-02T04:35:08.225Z [WARNING]: EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'vite@5.0.12',
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.0.0 || >=20.0.0' },
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.19.0', npm: '8.19.3' }
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-02-02T04:35:12.701Z [INFO]: added 219 packages, and audited 220 packages in 7s
2024-02-02T04:35:12.707Z [INFO]: 41 packages are looking for funding
                                 run `npm fund` for details
                                 found 0 vulnerabilities
2024-02-02T04:35:12.716Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
                                 # Starting phase: build
                                 # Executing command: npm run build
2024-02-02T04:35:13.029Z [INFO]: > nba-stat-tracker@0.0.0 build
                                 > tsc && vite build
2024-02-02T04:35:14.287Z [INFO]: src/App.tsx(1,1): error TS6133: 'useState' is declared but its value is never read.
2024-02-02T04:35:14.301Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2024-02-02T04:35:14.302Z [ERROR]: !!! Error: Command failed with exit code 2
2024-02-02T04:35:14.302Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2024-02-02T04:35:14.302Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

i tried setting the build file to run npm i instead of npm ci but that didnt work

Answer (score 0):

That's an easy fix :)
Take a look at this: 2024-02-02T04:35:14.287Z [INFO]: src/App.tsx(1,1): error TS6133: 'useState' is declared but its value is never read.

It does complain when you are not using things that you imported.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).